# Stop listening to provider after Signout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I use a multi-provider:

```
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<AuthenticationService>(
            create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
          ),
          StreamProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
            initialData: null,
          ),
          StreamProvider<UserData>(
            create: (context) => FirebaseService(
                    uid: Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context,
                            listen: false)
                        .getCurrentUID())
                .userData,
            initialData: null,
          ),
        ],
```

I watch in different widgets within the build method or in didChangeDependencies:

`UserData userData = context.watch<UserData>();`

After a user is signed out with

```
_firebaseAuth.currentUser.delete();
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/",
                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

I get the following error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<DocumentSnapshot, UserData> listened by
StreamProvider<UserData>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("uid")
...
Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1217 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /Users/XXX/development/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (3 months ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1
```

I think it has to do with the fact that when the user logs out, that a provider is still running. How can I prevent the provider from watching further?